# How to simulate failure conditions for ActiveMerchant and Authorize.net credit card processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, authorize.net, activemerchant

I've integrated ActiveMerchant into my Rails 3 app more or less along the lines outlined in the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant) on the topic using Authorize.net as my gateway.  I'm running the gateway in test mode (`ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test`) in development, and everything seems to be working as expected for the success case.  The credit card validation is working fine for incorrectly formatted input, but in order to fully verify my workflows, I'd like to also test purchase failure cases, such as insufficient funds or miss-matched CCV code.  Unfortunately, it seems that I'm receiving `response.success? == true` for any correctly formatted credit card number, at least when operating in test mode against my Authorize.net test account.

So, my question is: How should I simulate particular types of failures on my `gateway.purchase()` call?  Is there a test card number which always has insufficient funds?  Do I just need to dummy up my own `response` object?  What's the most correct approach here?

Caveat: I'm new to Ruby, Rails, and credit card processing, so please forgive me if the answer is desperately obvious.  Did a fair bit of Googling and couldn't find an example exercising the failure modes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the failure you want by using the proper zip code:

http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Triggering-Specific-Transaction-Responses-Using-Test-Account/m-p/4361

Comment: Note: Being able to generate declined transactions seems to be broken currently, but allegedly this pull request fixes it: https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/pull/785